# Overlapping Intervals in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, overlap

I am trying to separate data record into overlapping and non-overlapping periods in postgresql.
For example, the data I have is the following:

| start_date | end_date | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-28 | 2021-12-31 | a |
| 2021-03-09 | 2021-03-31 | b |

Since the above data overlaps in the date range from 2021-03-09 to 2021-03-31
I would like to have dates separated to reflect the overlapping and non overlapping periods
The desired output is:

| start_date | end_date | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-28 | 2021-03-08 | a |
| 2021-03-09 | 2021-03-31 | a , b |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-12-31 | a |

Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 1):

With `T` as your table, the query:

1. Extracts all the dates from `T`
2. Calculates all the ranges that exist, in order.
   It uses the `LAG` and `LEAD` window functions for that (`LAG` to know when to add 1 day to a lower bound, i.e. on all ranges except the first, `LEAD` associate 2 consecutive records and get a lower and an upper bounds on the same record.
3. Aggregates the type_ids in an array, in ascending order.

Query:

```
WITH AllDates(range_boundary) AS (
    SELECT start_date FROM T
    UNION 
    SELECT end_date FROM T
), AllRanges(lower_bound, upper_bound) AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(range_boundary) OVER (ORDER BY range_boundary) IS NULL then 0 else 1 END + range_boundary,
       LEAD(range_boundary) OVER (ORDER BY range_boundary)
FROM AllDates
)
SELECT 
    lower_bound AS start_date,
    upper_bound AS end_date,
    array_agg(type_id ORDER BY type_id) AS type_ids
FROM AllRanges
JOIN T ON AllRanges.lower_bound >= T.start_date and AllRanges.upper_bound <= T.end_date
GROUP BY lower_bound, upper_bound
ORDER BY start_date
```

Additional notes:

- More often than not, ranges are expressed as `[start, end)` (lower bound included, upper bound excluded).
  If you were to adopt this convention, there would be no need to add 1 day to every lower bound except the first one, making your query all the more simple (the lower bound of the next range is equal to the upper bound of the current range, since the latter is excluded from the range)
- If needed, you can easily cast `type_ids` to a string, using `array(...)::text`. From there, I let you remove the curly brackets yourself.